# How to send input to System.console.readLine(...) in Junit?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I have a main method I'd like to test.

I'm just wondering how to pass what the console.readLine(...) and console.readLine(...) is expecting from my Junit test - without refactoring main(...) - I'm using JMockit if that would be of use here - i.e. mocking out the System.console()?.

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();

        String username = console.readLine("Enter your username: ");
        char[] newPassword = console.readPassword("Enter your new password: ");

        ...
    }
}

class MyJunitTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass.main(null);
        // here I'd just like to pass the username and password to the console?
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot more going on in main(...) than just this, I need to get past this first in order to test the rest of it.

Comment: Why do you need to pass console.readLine(...) to main method ? Anyway Console object is created inside main method.

Comment: I believe this problem has been solved here: [JUnit testing with simulated user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415728/junit-testing-with-simulated-user-input). Simply set your own input stream for System.in.

Comment: Thanks @mttdbrd - I actually ended up using JMockit to do this, see my answer below.

Comment: The best answer is "don't do that". Break the API apart so that you can directly call the code that needs that input from your unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work using JMockit to mock the Console class:

```
  @Test
  public void test(
      @Mocked final System systemMock,
      @Mocked final Console consoleMock) {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {
      {
        System.console();
        result = consoleMock;

        consoleMock.readLine(anyString);
        result = "aUsername";

        consoleMock.readPassword(anyString);
        result = "aPassword";
      }
    };

    MyClass.main(null);
  }
```