# More verbose output for JUnit assertEquals when comparing big strings

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, junit

I just finished homework assignment and it passed automatic evaluation at the university. I thought of making unit tests for it, now that I know it's correct, to practice using `JUnit`.

I learned how to [override and read standard output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119559/607407) and [simulate standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416179/607407). I wrote myself a method:

```
public static void simulateIn(final String str) {
    // Simulated STDIN
    final ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
@Test
public void TestOnePlusOne() throws Exception {
    simulateIn("1 1 1 1");
    // Homework assignment executes here
    new Lab01().homework();
    // Expected input. I didn't translate it, but it's just a simple calculator
    assertEquals("Vyber operaci (1-soucet, 2-rozdil, 3-soucin, 4-podil):\n" +
                "Zadej scitanec: \n" +
                "Zadej scitanec: \n" +
                "Zadej pocet desetinnych mist: \n" +
                "1.0 + 1.0 = 2.0\n", outContent.toString());
}
```

I left the expected output untranslated, it really doesn't matter what it says right now. What matters is that the test fails and all I get is this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.TestCalculator
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.097 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   TestOnePlusOne(test.TestCalculator): expected:<...desetinnych mist: 

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

That's extremely unhelpful. Since I know the assignment is correct, this is something wrong with the unit test. Can I get the full diff of the strings that failed the `assertEquals`?

Comment: are you executing this using `mvn test` ? If so what maven version is in use?

Comment: I'm executing within netbeans. I'm not very experienced with this, so I honestly have no idea what commands do run in background.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to reproduce the same failure , I gave this a try with --

```
@Test
public void log() {
    Assert.assertEquals("Vyber operaci (1-soucet, 2-rozdil, 3-soucin, 4-podil):\n" +
            "Zadej scitanec: \n" +
            "Zadej scitanec: \n" +
            "Zadej pocet desetinnych mist: \n" +
            "1.0 + 1.0 = 2.0\n", ""); // empty string to make sure this fails
}
```

Executing command `mvn clean install` from the command line at the root directory on the module containing the above test class. It resulted in the following logs -

> ```
> Running TestOne
> true
> Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.356 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestOne
> log on log(TestOne)(TestOne)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< FAILURE!
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
> expected:<[Vyber operaci (1-soucet, 2-rozdil, 3-soucin, 4-podil):
> Zadej scitanec: 
> Zadej scitanec: 
> Zadej pocet desetinnych mist: 
> 1.0 + 1.0 = 2.0
> ]> but was:<[]>
>         at TestOne.log(TestOne.java:17)
> ```

Notice few details in the logs -

1. Running *TestOne*  - test class name
2. *log(TestOne)*  - name of the method
3. *org.junit.ComparisonFailure* type of failure
4. *expected* and actual ..*but was*

Just to ensure consistency, I've used `Apache Maven 3.3.9` and `maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1`

```
<dependencies>
  ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I couldn't run maven in the directory where tests are located. Running it in the project root produced the same output: http://pastebin.com/SMSviifP I have no plugins in pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/Darker/5ff47804ea1b8502583e95b2a4079b02#file-pom-xml Maven version: `Apache Maven 3.0.5` It's strange that you have newer version, I downloaded netbeans two weeks ago and maven was part of that download.

Comment: @TomášZato updating the surefire-plugin to 2.19.1 shall help you. You need to include the `<build>` tag at the same level as your dependencies tag.