# Java Command Interpreter Testing

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, command-line

Goal is pretty simple. Being able to test a very simple Command Interpreter.

I'm currently using TestNG to test a Java application that has a command interpreter in its root. But I'm not being able to accomplish this.

As soon as the application starts it enters a loop that processes the user input and chooses where to go from there () and only stops if the user's input equals *"exit"*. The *printHelp()* method prints all the available commands.

Can you tell me how I should proceed in order to test the *printHelp()* method in a way to simulate a user's input and getting the right output.

**Note:** Assume that the *printHelp()* method is supposed to print the string *"All the info needed"*.

The maven dependency as well as the Main Class are provided below.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Java Main Class**

```java
public static void main(String args[]){
    menu();
}
```

```java
private static void menu() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] fullLine;
    StringConst.CMDS cmd; //enum of prossible cmds

    do {
        System.out.print(StringConst.PROMPT); //aesthetic
        fullLine = in.nextLine().toUpperCase().split(" ");
        cmd = StringConst.CMDS.fromString(fullLine[0]);

        switch (cmd) {
            (...)
            case HELP:
                printHelp();
                break;
            case EXIT:
                System.out.println("Exiting...");
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println(StringConst.NOT_FOUND);
                break;
        }

    } while (!cmd.equals(StringConst.CMDS.EXIT));
}
```

```java
private static void printHelp() {
    for (StringConst.CMDS cmd : StringConst.CMDS.values()) {
        System.out.println(cmd + " - " + cmd.getDescription());
    }
}
```

**StringConst Class**

```java
public class StringConst {

    public static final String NOT_FOUND = "Command not found... Please try again.";
    public static final String PROMPT = "> ";

    public enum CMDS {
        HELP, EXIT, OTHER;

        private String description;

        static {
            HELP.description = "Prints each command's function";
            EXIT.description = "Exits the program";
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public static CMDS fromString(String temp) {
            return CMDS.valueOf(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit testing with simulated user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415728/junit-testing-with-simulated-user-input)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Apoligies, that is a custom made class. With just constants and enums. Editing atm

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam I've seen and tried that method but that method assumes that there's not a main running in the background. It tests a solo method. I'm wanting to test the interpreter in itself.

Comment: The interpreter is a "solo" method, just a complicated one. Pass in input and output, either as `*Stream`s or as a `Reader`/`Writer` pair.

Comment: @Asfourhundred why don't you pass scanner as parameter in `menu` method and use your input stream to simulate use action?