# How to test method without args using the spock framework

Tags: java, spock

I can't figure out how to test this. Tell me please good literature or vebinar on this topic

```
public InputMessenger getInputForMessengerFromConsole() {
    String templateValue;
    Map<String, String> valuesForTemplate = new HashMap<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, Constant.CHARSET_NAME_UTF_8)) {
        System.out.println(Constant.MESSAGE_INPUT_TEMPLATE);
        templateValue = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(Constant.MESSAGE_NUMBER_OF_VALUES);
        int numberOfValues = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        IntStream.range(0, numberOfValues).forEach(index -> {
            System.out.println(Constant.MESSAGE_KEY + (index + Constant.INT_ONE) + Constant.COLON);
            String key = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(Constant.MESSAGE_VALUE + (index + Constant.INT_ONE) + Constant.COLON);
            String value = scanner.nextLine();
            valuesForTemplate.put(key, value);
        });
    }
    return new InputMessenger(templateValue, valuesForTemplate);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question. So that the community members could understand the problem precisely.

Comment: @JesvinVijeshS I need to write a test for a given method using the Spock framework but I can't figure it out. Could you please help me with this? Maybe you can suggest some literature or how this can be implemented

Comment: Have you tried the official Spock manual for starters? If you study it, you should be able to learn everything you need to know about how to test your code. Besides, this kind of question looking for book or website recommendations is off topic here on SO.

Comment: You should probably look into breaking down the method into smaller methods that can then be easily tested.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Do not tell me, but how can you even mock at the scanner. I mean, how to pass the value in the test to the console?

Comment: @TrakPolisi check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415728/junit-testing-with-simulated-user-input and write java code in groovy style for spock testing

Answer (score 1):

This is a draft (I didn’t check it):

```
setup: 
def originalIn = System.in
def originalOut = System.out

and: "Define new out:"

def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
System.setOut(new PrintStream(out))

and: "Define input data and specify in"

def input = "…input data for test…"
def in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes())
System.setIn(in)

when:
def result = getInputForMessengerFromConsole()

then:
out.toString() == expectedOutput

and:
result == expectedResult

cleanup:
System.setOut(originalOut)
System.setIn(originalIn)
```